# passing string data from onPostExecute method of AsyncTask to other activity

Tags: android, android-asynctask

my question is:In android programming how to pass the string data like name,address that we obtained in onPostExecute() method of AsyncTask to another activity that will receive this string data.for example i want to pass string name, url that i got in onPostExecute() method and then transfer these string data to another activity via dosomething() function and start that activity. please reply asap.Thanx in advance.please explain solution code.

**PlaceDetailsActivity**

```
 import org.json.JSONObject;

 import android.app.Activity;
 import android.app.ProgressDialog;
 import android.content.Intent;
 import android.os.AsyncTask;
 import android.os.Bundle;
 import android.util.Log;
 import android.view.View;
 import android.webkit.WebView;

 public class PlaceDetailsActivity extends Activity {
 WebView mWvPlaceDetails;


 ProgressDialog pDialog;



protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_details);

    // Getting reference to WebView ( wv_place_details ) of the layout activity_place_details
    mWvPlaceDetails = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.wv_place_details);

    mWvPlaceDetails.getSettings().setUseWideViewPort(false);

    // Getting place reference from the map
    String reference = getIntent().getStringExtra("reference");

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder("https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/details/json?");
    sb.append("reference="+reference);
    sb.append("&sensor=true");
    sb.append("&key=AIzaSyChVcy-8fLkAq5-ZJCuNomF1lIf-Gda7s8");

    // Creating a new non-ui thread task to download Google place details
    PlacesTask placesTask = new PlacesTask();

    // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class PlaceTask
    placesTask.execute(sb.toString());

};

/** A method to download json data from url */
private String downloadUrl(String strUrl) throws IOException{
    String data = "";
    InputStream iStream = null;
    HttpURLConnection urlConnection = null;
    try{
        URL url = new URL(strUrl);

        // Creating an http connection to communicate with url
        urlConnection = (HttpURLConnection) url.openConnection();

        // Connecting to url
        urlConnection.connect();

        // Reading data from url
        iStream = urlConnection.getInputStream();

        BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(iStream));

        StringBuffer sb = new StringBuffer();

        String line = "";
        while( ( line = br.readLine()) != null){
            sb.append(line);
        }

        data = sb.toString();
            br.close();

    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.d("Exception while downloading url", e.toString());
    }finally{
        iStream.close();
        urlConnection.disconnect();
    }
    return data;
}
/** A class, to download Google Place Details */
private class PlacesTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, String>{

     /**
     * Before starting background thread Show Progress Dialog
     * */
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(PlaceDetailsActivity.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading Restaurent Details ...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        pDialog.show();
    }
    String data = null;

    // Invoked by execute() method of this object
    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(String... url) {
        try{
            data = downloadUrl(url[0]);
        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Background Task",e.toString());
        }
        return data;
    }

    // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result){
        ParserTask parserTask = new ParserTask();

        // Start parsing the Google place details in JSON format
        // Invokes the "doInBackground()" method of the class ParseTask
        parserTask.execute(result);
    }
}

/** A class to parse the Google Place Details in JSON format */
private class ParserTask extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, HashMap<String,String>>{

    JSONObject jObject;

    // Invoked by execute() method of this object
    @Override
    protected HashMap<String,String> doInBackground(String... jsonData) {

        HashMap<String, String> name = null;
        HashMap<String, String> hPlaceDetails = null;
        PlaceDetailsJSONParser placeDetailsJsonParser = new PlaceDetailsJSONParser();

        try{
            jObject = new JSONObject(jsonData[0]);

            // Start parsing Google place details in JSON format
            hPlaceDetails = placeDetailsJsonParser.parse(jObject);
            name = placeDetailsJsonParser.parse(jObject);


        }catch(Exception e){
            Log.d("Exception",e.toString());
        }
        return hPlaceDetails;
        return name;//(here eclise gives error unrechable code)
    }

    // Executed after the complete execution of doInBackground() method
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(HashMap<String,String> hPlaceDetails){



        // dismiss the dialog after getting all products
        pDialog.dismiss();

        String name = hPlaceDetails.get("name");
        String icon = hPlaceDetails.get("icon");
        String vicinity = hPlaceDetails.get("vicinity");
        String lat = hPlaceDetails.get("lat");
        String lng = hPlaceDetails.get("lng");
        String formatted_address = hPlaceDetails.get("formatted_address");
        String formatted_phone = hPlaceDetails.get("formatted_phone");
        String website = hPlaceDetails.get("website");
        String rating = hPlaceDetails.get("rating");
        String international_phone_number = hPlaceDetails.get("international_phone_number");
        String url = hPlaceDetails.get("url");





        String mimeType = "text/html";
        String encoding = "utf-8";

        String data = "<html>"+
                      "<body><img style='float:left' src="+icon+" /><h1><center>"+name+"</center></h1>" +
                      "<br style='clear:both' />" +
                      "<hr />"+
                      //"<p>Vicinity : " + vicinity + "</p>" +
                      //"<p>Location : " + lat + "," + lng + "</p>" +
                      "<p>Address : " + formatted_address + "</p>" +
                      "<p>Phone : " + formatted_phone + "</p>" +
                      "<p>Website : " + website + "</p>" +
                      "<p>Rating : " + rating + "</p>" +
                      "<p>International Phone : " + international_phone_number + "</p>" +
                      "<p>Reviews(Please Open in Web browser) : <a href='" + url + "'>" + url + "</p>" +
                      "</body></html>";

        // Setting the data in WebView
        mWvPlaceDetails.loadDataWithBaseURL("", data, mimeType, encoding, "");
    }
}


public void dosomething(View v)
{




 if (v.getId()==R.id.button2)
 {



 }
 else if (v.getId()==R.id.button3)
 {

 }

}
  }
```

**PlaceJSONParser  class**:

```
             public class PlaceJSONParser {

       /** Receives a JSONObject and returns a list */
      public List<HashMap<String,String>> parse(JSONObject jObject){

     JSONArray jPlaces = null;
    try {
        /** Retrieves all the elements in the 'places' array */
        jPlaces = jObject.getJSONArray("results");
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    /** Invoking getPlaces with the array of json object
    * where each json object represent a place
    */
    return getPlaces(jPlaces);
}

private List<HashMap<String, String>> getPlaces(JSONArray jPlaces){
    int placesCount = jPlaces.length();
    List<HashMap<String, String>> placesList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> place = null;

    /** Taking each place, parses and adds to list object */
    for(int i=0; i<placesCount;i++){
        try {
            /** Call getPlace with place JSON object to parse the place */
            place = getPlace((JSONObject)jPlaces.get(i));
            placesList.add(place);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return placesList;
}

/** Parsing the Place JSON object */
private HashMap<String, String> getPlace(JSONObject jPlace){

    HashMap<String, String> place = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String placeName = "-NA-";
    String vicinity="-NA-";
    String latitude="";
    String longitude="";
    String reference="";

    try {
        // Extracting Place name, if available
        if(!jPlace.isNull("name")){
            placeName = jPlace.getString("name");
        }

        // Extracting Place Vicinity, if available
        if(!jPlace.isNull("vicinity")){
            vicinity = jPlace.getString("vicinity");
        }

        latitude = jPlace.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lat");
        longitude = jPlace.getJSONObject("geometry").getJSONObject("location").getString("lng");
        reference = jPlace.getString("reference");

        place.put("place_name", placeName);
        place.put("vicinity", vicinity);
        place.put("lat", latitude);
        place.put("lng", longitude);
        place.put("reference", reference);

    } catch (JSONException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return place;
  }
 }
```

**PlaceDetails class**:

```
 import java.io.Serializable;

   import com.google.api.client.util.Key;

/** Implement this class from "Serializable"
 * So that you can pass this class Object to another using Intents
   * Otherwise you can't pass to another actitivy
  * */
   public class PlaceDetails implements Serializable {

@Key
public String status;

@Key
public Place result;

@Override
public String toString() {
    if (result!=null) {
        return result.toString();
    }
    return super.toString();
 }
 }
```

Any help is appreciated !

Comment: Please post your logcat so that we can see the error type

Comment: my question is:In android programming how to pass the string data like name,address that we obtained in onPostExecute() method of AsyncTask to another activity that will receive this string data.for example i want to pass string name, url that i got in     onPostExecute() method and then transfer these string data to another activity via dosomething() fuction and start that activity. please reply asap.Thanx in advance.please wxplain me solution code.  see above code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my opinion two options are available on the table!

1.Create your `AsyncTask` class as an inner class inside your `Activity` class, and then you can gain access for all super class properties.

```
public class MyActivity extends Activity {

    int property1;
    void method1() {

    }

    private class MyTask extents AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void param)
            method1(...); // <-- this is method of the enclosing class
        }
    }
}
```

2.Define a public interface for your `AsyncTask` class and call its listener in the `onPostExecute`

```
public class MyTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Void, Void> {

    OnTaskFinishedListener mListener;

    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void param)
        if(mListener != null){
            mListenr.onFinished(...); // <-- call your callback
        } 
    }

    public void setOnTaskFinishedListener(OnTaskFinishedListener listener) {
        mListener = listener;
    }

    public interface OnTaskFinishedListener {
        public void onFinished(...);
    }

}
```